# regex pattern for tags needed

Tags: c#, regex, tags

Howzit,

I need help with the following please.

I need to find tags in a string.  These tags start with `{{` and end with `}}`, there will be multiple tags in the string I receive.

So far I have this, but it doesn't find any matches, what am I missing here?

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

string pattern = "{{*}}";

Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = r.Match(text);

while (m.Success)
{
    list.Add(m.Groups[0].Value);

    m = m.NextMatch();
}


return list;
```

even tried `string pattern = "{{[A-Za-z0-9]}}";`
thanx

PS. I know close to nothing about regex.

Comment: is this C#? - please always put the language you're using as a tag, because there are small differences between the regex "flavors"

Comment: your expression specifies, essentially: "find a `{`, then match a `{` (zero to an infinite number of times), then match `}}`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only do you want to use {{.+?}} as your regex, you also need to pass RegexOptions.SingleLine.  That will treat your entire string as a single line and the . will match \n (which it normally will not do).

Answer (score 1):

Try `{{.+}}`. The `.+` means there has to be at least one character as part of the tag.

EDIT:

To capture the string containing your tags you can do `{{(.+)}}` and then tokenize your match with the Tokenize or Scanner class?

Comment: however the list I get is the whole text and not just the tag found :(

Comment: Check the m.Groups array for more matches, the match in brackets is usually has the index of 1. The 0 index is the entire matched string.

Comment: theres only 1 in the M.Groups list. which includes the whole string

Comment: so, I realize that if there is only one tag, it returns just the tag, if there is more, it returns everything

Comment: ie, if the string is `{{test1}} and {{test2}} and test3`, it returns `{{test1}} and {{test2}}` so it doesnt find the first `}}`

Comment: adding `?` to the pattern solves this!!  thank you very much, the pattern is now `{{.+?}}`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying something like the following:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

string pattern = "{{(.*?)}}";

Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = r.Match(text);

while (m.Success)
{
    list.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);

    m = m.NextMatch();
}

return list;
```

the regex specifies:

```
{{       # match {{ literally
(        # begin capturing into group #1
  .*?    # match any characters, from zero to infinite, but be lazy*
)        # end capturing group
}}       # match }} literally
```

"lazy" means to attempt to continue matching the pattern afterwards "`}}`" before backtracking to the `.*?` and reluctantly adding a character to the capturing group *only* if the character does not match `}}` - hope that made sense.

I changed your code by modifying the regex and to extract the *first matching group* from the regex match object (`m.Groups[1].value`) instead of the entire match.

Answer (score 0):

`{{.*?}}` or 
`{{.+?}}`

. - means any symbol

? - means lazy(don't capute nextpattern)